# Return values from SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server that returns two values. When called from QA with the following SQL code:

```
exec TWEEPush_ValidateCO @CoFilter='CO IN(''1502'',''Mike'',''Clarkson'')', @TDate='09/18/`2017'
```

it works as expected by returning two values:

```
@TempCOID   @TempDate  
1502        09/10/2017
```

The stored procedure does some work and ends with the two values being set to non null values, with the stored procedure ending with:

```
SELECT 
    @TempCOID AS N'@TempCOID',  
    @TempDate AS N'@TempDate'
```

In VB.net (Visual Basic, not C), I've tried many different approaches to get the results but have had no luck. Either I get an error saying the named param doesn't exist, or it ends up returning empty values (everything is coded to prevent Nulls in the return data)

```vb
Dim sConnectStr As String = GetSQLConnectionString()

Try
    Using Connection As New SqlConnection(sConnectStr)
        Connection.Open()

        Dim Command As New SqlCommand("dbo.TWEEPush_ValidateCO", Connection)
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoFilter", Filter)
        Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDate", Now())

        Dim PramCOIDRet As New SqlParameter
        PramCOIDRet.ParameterName = "@TempCOID"
        PramCOIDRet.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
        PramCOIDRet.Size = 30
        PramCOIDRet.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        Dim PramDateRet As New SqlParameter
        PramDateRet.ParameterName = "@TempDate"
        PramDateRet.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar
        PramDateRet.Size = 30
        PramDateRet.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output

        Command.Parameters.Add(PramCOIDRet)
        Command.Parameters.Add(PramDateRet)

        Command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        Dim COID as string = Command.Parameters("@TempCOID").Value
        Dim CoDate as Date = CDate(Command.Parameters("@TempDate").Value)
    End Using
Catch ex As Exception
End Try
```

No matter what code I've tried, the code never returns the data as expected.
What am I doing wrong? Can someone please shed some light on this please?

Comment: Despite the rather odd column names being used, those "parameters" aren't actually parameters. You'll just get a normal result set back with a single row in it, with the values in that. You should use ExecuteReader rather than ExecuteNonQuery (because it really is actually a query; that's what the `SELECT` is doing) and then grab the results from there.

Comment: what if you check  `PramDateRet.Value` and `PramCOIDRet.Value`

Comment: That procedure looks suspiciously like it is receiving a string and executing it as dynamic sql. This is very scary and is very likely vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: This code is being fed a company ID that is validated by the stored proc.  If the company ID proves to be a valid id,both the valid company id (there may be casing issues hence the official version of the company id) and a date (as stored elsewhere and is needed here) are returned.  I'll see if I can re-approach this as a single query.

Comment: If it is validating it with dynamic sql it is too late. You really be using proper parameters. Table valued parameters are perfect for this type of thing.

Comment: Whats the body of the proc look like?

Comment: Sean; the data sent into the SQL server is selected from a drop down that is populated from an outside source.  The actual data is not in the original case, which is problematic later on.  So, the data is sent for validation against the db, and the correct proper case data is returned.  Q: What do you mean by 'proper parameters'?  I've tried all combinations of such.  Can you give a url of an example of this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't show us your stored procedure code - but most likely, it's something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.dbo.TWEEPush_ValidateCO
    @CoFilter VARCHAR(100),   -- just guessing here!
    @TDate DATE               -- again - just guessing 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempCOID INT;
    DECLARE @TempDate DATE;

    -- do some calculations here that define @TempCOID and @TempDate
    -- this is just for demo purposes - I'm sure your calculation is a bit
    -- more complex and involved...
    SET @TempCOID = 1502;
    SET @TempDate = '20170910';

    -- return the values in a SELECT statement
    SELECT 
        @TempCOID AS N'@TempCOID',  
        @TempDate AS N'@TempDate'
END
```

In this case, you're **returning a RESULT SET** - not two parameters!

You need to get your values like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    int tempCoid;
    DateTime tempDate;

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.dbo.TWEEPush_ValidateCO", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CoFilter", Filter);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDate", DateTime.Now);

        conn.Open();

        using (var rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rdr.Read())
            {
                tempCoid = rdr.GetFieldValue<int>(0);
                tempDate = rdr.GetFieldValue<DateTime>(1);
            }
        }

        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

(I'm sure you get the idea - and you can easily translate this into VB.NET, too).

Hope that helps!

Marc

Comment: Marc; this is as close as it is inside the code and SQL proc.  Sadly, I still am not getting values.  I haven't had time today to work through what will most likely be my coding fault (ie not your example).  IN any and every case, the returned values from the SP are never and can never be null.  They can be empty, but never null.

Comment: @RGS: I have really nothing additional to say beyond what's already been said in those comments

Comment: This worked for the most part; thank's for the insight.  I don't know why I didn't think of that.  Anyway, thank you!